# iOS 7 static table view selection style bug

Tags: static, ios7, tableview, uitableview

I think I found a little iOS 7 bug..

If you have a **static** table view as a part of a navigation view controller and the user use **the swipe back gesture** to get one level back, the selection highlight doesn't dismiss!
(if the user press the back navigation bar button the selection dismiss normal)

Does anybody also detect this bug?
Does anybody has a fix for that?

Thank you a lot

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this could be:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

inside the `viewDidAppear` method. (not tested)